# Firestore PHP SDK issues in installation

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am following tutorial located at
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers

1. gRPC installed
2. Login to my account via Putty
3. SDK installed via composer
4. Run and verifeid export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/firebase-php-sdk/hcare-230207-521d43bf5e6d.json"
5. When I initialize client I get error located at: https://m.hatemyfat.com/?firestore

Code I use is same as per instructions:

```
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
require '/home/hatemyfat/sdks/vendor/autoload.php';
$firestore = new FirestoreClient();
```

I am sure there is something quick to be fixed so looking forward for expert help to get started

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now? I clicked on the link and I got some valid-looking json response.